# Can we use a repository from another Symfony project?

Tags: symfony

I will create a new Symfony project and I would like to know if it is possible to use a repository from another Symfony project of mine.

UPDATE
I have a Symfony project accessible inside my company and we would like to create another Symfony project accessible outside that would use some of the bundles from inside.

Comment: Might consider adding a few more details to your question to stop the down voting.  Obviously you can copy/paste your repository code from one project to another.  But I suspect you are asking for a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

You can package your repository as vendor. More about it [here](https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/bundles/best_practices.html)

Comment: Just for info, link only answers are considered to be as bad as context free questions.

Comment: Thanks for the tips!